# Cannot link sctp binary

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, sctp

I'm doing a network **C library** and I want to support also *SCTP*.
I have in this file wrapper_socket_functions.c

```
/*SCTP WRAPPER */
void
Sctp_bindx(int sd, struct sockaddr *addrs, int addrcnt, int flags)
{
    int rbindx = sctp_bindx(sd, addrs, addrcnt, flags);
    if(rbindx == -1)
        prog_error("Sctp_bindx error",true,errno);
}
void
Sctp_connectx(int sd, struct sockaddr *addrs, int addrcnt, sctp_assoc_t *id)
{
    int rconnectx = sctp_connectx(sd, addrs, addrcnt, id);
    if(rconnectx == -1)
        prog_error("Sctp_connectx error",true,errno);
}
int
Sctp_peeloff(int sd, sctp_assoc_t assoc_id)
{
    int rpeeloff = sctp_peeloff(sd, assoc_id);
    if(rpeeloff == -1)
        prog_error("Sctp_paleof error",true,errno);
    return rpeeloff;
}
```

And i have this makefile.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lsctp -c -std=gnu11 -g -Wall -o
LIB_PATH = lib/
BIN_PATH = bin/

OBJECTS_LIBRARY = bin/error.o bin/signal.o bin/io_socket.o bin/wrapper_socket_functions.o bin/wrapper_stdio.o bin/wrapper_convert.o bin/wrapper_io_socket.o bin/wrapper_unix.o bin/handlers.o bin/miscellaneous.o bin/protocol.o
CLIENT_FILES = bin/client.o
SERVER_FILES = bin/server.o

all:

    #Compile MAIN_FILES

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)client.o client.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)server.o server.c

    #Compile LIB_FILES

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)handlers.o $(LIB_PATH)handlers.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)signal.o $(LIB_PATH)signal.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)error.o $(LIB_PATH)error.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)wrapper_socket_functions.o $(LIB_PATH)wrapper_socket_functions.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)wrapper_stdio.o $(LIB_PATH)wrapper_stdio.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)wrapper_convert.o $(LIB_PATH)wrapper_convert.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)wrapper_io_socket.o $(LIB_PATH)wrapper_io_socket.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)io_socket.o $(LIB_PATH)io_socket.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)wrapper_unix.o $(LIB_PATH)wrapper_unix.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)miscellaneous.o $(LIB_PATH)miscellaneous.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_PATH)protocol.o $(LIB_PATH)protocol.c
    #Link CLIENT

    $(CC) -o $(BIN_PATH)client $(OBJECTS_LIBRARY) $(CLIENT_FILES)

    #Link SERVER

    $(CC) -o $(BIN_PATH)server $(OBJECTS_LIBRARY) $(SERVER_FILES)

    #Remove unwanted objects

    rm -rf bin/*.o
```

The problem is when I link them together in two different bin **server** and **client** it tells me this:

`undefined reference to sctp_bindx
 undefined reference to sctp_connectx
 undefined reference to sctp_peeloff`

Note that when I compile with `-lsctp` it compiles fine but, when I try to link that *.o file it complains like above. Also I have installed the **lksctp_tools** and checked if my kernel support it with **checksctp**

```
~ $ checksctp
Sctp supported
```

Comment: Linker libraries should always be placed *last*, after all object files depending on the library.

Comment: I tried,but it still complains..

Comment: Maybe because you don't use any flags when linking?

Comment: By the way, that's a very odd makefile, usually one uses rules so you don't have to compile/link files that haven't changed instead of always rebuilding everything like you do.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, it works now ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you please share the complete code for multihomed server client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `CFLAGS` arg `-lsctp` and add this in `LINKFLAGS = -lsctp` and when linking add after `$(CC) $(LINKFLAGS).`

Comment: By convention one calls `LDFLAGS` what you call `LINKFLAGS`.